# mysql change date format

Tags: mysql

I have a date field (tinytext) holding date information in format of  "dd-mm-yy" e.g 07-01-90. Using a mysql query I want to change it to yyyy-mm-dd date format. I tried the code below but nothing happens.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Table SET date=STR_TO_DATE('date','%Y,%m,%d')");
```

Comment: try with [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using the correct function `STR_TO_DATE(str,format)` to achieve the goal, but you're making two mistakes:

1. In your query the *`format`* argument does not match the string expression format. You said it's in `dd-mm-yy` format while you passed `%Y,%m,%d` (comma separated) to the *`format`* argument. The query will return a "incorrect datetime value" error. You should use `%d-%m-%Y`.
2. You can't change data type of a column on the fly, by setting different type of the value being passed. You have to first update the values and then change data type for column.

So, summarizing:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `Table` SET `date` = STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d-%m-%Y')");
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `Table` CHANGE COLUMN `date` `date` DATE");
```

Additionally, consider switching to the recommended [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension in place of old and [slowly deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) `mysql` extension.

Answer (score 5):

Error in your query

is STR_TO_DATE(**date, '%Y-%m-%d'**)

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Table SET date=STR_TO_DATE(date,'%Y-%m-%d')");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO table(date_field) VALUES(STR_TO_DATE('December 8, 2010','%M %d,%Y'));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To display **2** digit year

   `mysql_query("UPDATE Table SET date=DATE_FORMAT(date,'%y-%m-%d')");`
2. To display **4** digit year

   `mysql_query("UPDATE Table SET date=DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d')");`

Comment: This query does not convert format... it is probably because the field is "tinytext" not DATE or TIMESTAMP.

Comment: you meant variable `date` is of varchar type??

Answer (score 1):

Try it with [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE Table SET date=DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y,%m,%d')");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you have to do this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET date = DATE_FORMAT('date', %Y-%m-%d);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using my_sql with php, you can use [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function