# MySQL replace field entry with substring

Tags: php, mysql, date, substring

I currently have dates stored in my database (in string format) currently as mm/dd/yyyy.

I need to replace all entries as yyyy/mm/dd for sorting purposes.

To clarify, I am a PHP developer but my raw MySql isnt as strong. I was thinking of doing this by using substrings to re-arrange the date. (I tried in PHP first but it take way too long to process this much data, about a half million rows).

Am i going about this correctly? if so, how do I "loop through" the data, assigning my substr variables for the current iteration?

Note: I did try str_to_date here and it ended up nullifying half of the fields. Im not entirely sure why.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426993/mysql-change-date-format

Comment: you are looking for insert or update or select statment ?

Comment: And here we have *the exact reason* why the DATE and DATETIME data types exist.

Comment: To clarify, i am looking for an Update statement (sorry i should have said so) im also importing millions of rows from .CSV files with variable fields so importing as DATE was not an option here unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will work if your column is in a consistent mm/dd/yyyy format

```
UPDATE mytable
SET date = CONCAT(right(date,4), '/', left(date,5))
```

Answer (score 1):

this is an insert statment

```
  INSERT INTO yourtable (datefield) VALUES (str_to_date(date, '%Y/%m/%d'));
```

and this an update

```
 UPDATE Table SET date=STR_TO_DATE('date','%Y/%m/%d')
```

try this

```
   UPDATE Table SET date = DATE_FORMAT('date', %Y/%m/$d);
```

Comment: I tried your update statement exactly as written and all rows are now NULL for that field. Ideas?

Comment: look my updated answer

Comment: It is still nullifying the data. Very strange. But Matts answer below has worked perfectly so I can just go with that.