# Automatically change date format when inserting in MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv

I try to insert an csv file into mysql table. And one of the column in the file have date format like this: **3/15/2013 17:41:38** . Is it possible to insert the column, and change the date format become like this: **2013-03-15 17:41:38** ?

Thanks before

Comment: Look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426993/mysql-change-date-format

Comment: How do you intend to insert those entries? Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) for your insert, so you can put:

```
STR_TO_DATE( '3/15/2013 17:41:38', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s' )
```

as your date column.

The format reffers to the format of the input string, and the output format will be the standard MySQL date format as you need.

The output should be as:

```
mysql> select STR_TO_DATE( '3/15/2013 17:41:38', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s' );
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE( '3/15/2013 17:41:38', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s' ) |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 2013-03-15 17:41:38                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks but why when i use it the result give NULL value.

Comment: It works for me: 
`mysql> select STR_TO_DATE( '3/15/2013 17:41:38', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s' );
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE( '3/15/2013 17:41:38', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s' ) |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 2013-03-15 17:41:38                                      |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)`  *(Sorry, I can't properly format the output on a comment.*

Comment: @Jester don't comment, click "edit" on your answer to update it with more information.

Comment: @thenoirlatte If the solution worked for you, accept it as correct and upvote it please. ;)

Comment: i'm sorry, my reputation not enough to vote up, it needs 15 reputation :(